# 2 databases with 1 User on laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I currently use the laravel 3 database class on my own custom non-laravel website, but am rebuilding the site on laravel 4. I have 2 websites that share the same database that contains `product` tables, then each site has its own database for site specific tables like `orders`.

Heres what i currently use with the laravel 3 database class.

```
/**
* /database/connection.php
* Prepend database names onto tables.
*/
private function prepend_database_names($sql)
{
    $tables = array('product', 'product_brand'); // etc...

    if (is_array($tables))
    {   
        foreach($tables as $table)
        {
            $sql = preg_replace("/`$table`/", 'shared_db.`'.$table.'`', $sql);
        }   
    }

    return $sql;
}

// This is put inside the execute function

protected function execute($sql, $bindings = array())
{
    // other code...

    $sql = $this->prepend_database_names($sql);

    // other code...
}
```

**I'd like to do something similar but without editing any files inside the vendor folder.**
Unless someone knows a better way.

I don't have much knowledge in this area. Maybe extend the L4 database class and store a list of the table names from the shared database into the L4 `config/database.php` file?

**Edit:**

Heres an example of a query. This works fine because i added `shared.` before product, but i don't want to have to do that every time i use a table from the shared database.

```
DB::table('searches')
    ->join('shared.product', 'product.id', '=', 'searches.product_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: What if you just set the $table on the model to 'shared.product' ?

Comment: I just tried that and doesn't seem to work. Wouldn't the Product model not be used with query builder anyways?

Comment: If you're using fluent, writing out the queries like in your edit, then you don't have any choice but to write them out in full every time.  MySQL doesn't have any way of searching for tables in other databases (Postgres sort of does with schemas).  If you're using Eloquent then you may be able to set the $table on all models.

Comment: Yes, when using models your suggestion works. But is it possible do something similar to what i did with the laravel 3 database class above?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [solution](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=6386#p6386) by Phill Sparks that works in Laravel 3.

In Laravel 4 you can edit your connection in app/config/database.php

```
// app/config/database.php
'default' => 'first',
'connections' => array(
    'first' => array(
        'driver'   => 'mysql',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'database1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),
   'second' => array(
        'driver'   => 'mysql',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'database1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'   => '',
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help my current situation because theres only 1 connection for 2 databases. Another words 1 mysql user has rights to 2 mysql databases.